# Mapped type that unions variations of the given type?

Tags: typescript, union-types

Given a type that contains all possibilities (e.g. non-tagged union):

```
type Input = {
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean,
};
```

I want to map it with this kind of API:

```
type MapItSomehow<T> = ???;

type Output = MapItSomehow<Input>;
```

And ultimately get this:

```
type Output = {
  a: string,
  b: undefined,
  c: undefined,
} | {
  a: undefined,
  b: number,
  c: undefined,
} | {
  a: undefined,
  b: undefined,
  c: boolean,
};
```

The proof that this works is if I can do:

```
let r: Result = ([] as Result[])[0];

if ('a' in r) {
  r.a.trim() // not r.a!.trim()
}
else if // same for each field ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to make all other properties `undefined` instead making them optional ?

Comment: Optional might be better, yeah. In either case, see my updated question for how I'm using it. In practice, I'm using this for an API where the user can return `{ redirect: string} | { text: string } | { json: any }`.

Comment: made an update\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) and [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion):

```js
type Input = {
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean,
};

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Mapped<T> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: Record<Prop, T[Prop]>
}>


type Result = Mapped<Input>

declare let x: Result

if ('a' in x) {
  x.a.trim()
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnXrkW)

`Mapped` - iterates through each property and creates new part of expected union type where current key is set and other keys `Exclude<keyof T, Prop>` are `undefined`

`Values` - obtains a union type of all object values

Comment: When accessing the result, this doesn't have the effect I'm hoping for. Updated my question.

Comment: Perfect, extremely clever solution. A real untagged union, that works 100%. Nice job